# No consigo que se muestre un JPanel con un mensaje (drawString), aparece el JFrame sin nada

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy aprendiendo swing y mientras practicaba unos videotutoriales, he intentado que se muestre en el frame una lamina o panel con un mensaje, usando para ello Graphics y una clase que extiende de JPanel.

El esquema del proyecto es el siguiente...

[image: El esquema del proyecto.]

En el main ahora mismo simplemente hay un 
"VentanaInicio frame = new VentanaInicio();"

VentanaInicio es una clase que extiende de JFrame, cuyo código actual es:

```
initComponents();
    Utilidades utilidad = new Utilidades();
    utilidad.top(this);

    UtilidadesPintar elemento = new UtilidadesPintar();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();          
    panel.add(elemento);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Aparte de esto netbeans añade

```
 /**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Por último la clase en cuestión que debería pintar el mensaje y el panel (la de Utilidades solo se ocupa de centrar la ventana o ponerla en lo alto)...

```
public class UtilidadesPintar extends JPanel {
 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { 
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawString("Estamos aprendiendo Swing", 100, 100);
    }
```

}

Llevo un buen tiempo probando todas las combinaciones que se me ocurren en VentanaInicio, y buscando distintas preguntas con problemas similares, pero da igual lo que haga no se muestra, cambiándolo de sitio porque el setVisible provoca problemas, haciendo visibles todos los componentes, haciéndolos enable y luego visible etc, y por más que intento no se donde esta el error y porque no se muestra, quedando la pantalla tras la ejecución así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el método `initComponents` se usa `getContentPane().setLayout(layout);` eso sugiere que el contenedor que va a mostrar los componentes es un contenedor raiz o de `JRootPane`, consecuentemente hay que agregar cada elemento Swing o AWT a un `JPanel` que esté contenido por dicho `JRootPane`, de que manera?

La solución:

```
initComponents();
Utilidades utilidad = new Utilidades();
utilidad.top(this);

UtilidadesPintar elemento = new UtilidadesPintar();
elemento.setPreferredSize(getSize());

JPanel panel = new JPanel();          
panel.add(elemento);
//panel.setVisible(true); Un panel es visible por defecto.

//add(panel); Puesto directamente en 'Frame' no se puede ver
setContentPane(panel);//'panel' al estar dentro del rootpane es totalmente visible
this.setVisible(true);
```

Usando el `GroupLayout` hay que especificar las dimensiones del contenedor `elemento` via `setPreferredSize`, dato no menor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que el que swing sea tan puntilloso con todos los detalles y muchos no sean explicados o sean explicados de forma diferente en cada tutorial que veo no ayuda.